# Sunburnt arbitrary search

Tags: solr, sunburnt

I am using sunburnt solar API I want to make a query like this

```
solrconn.query(solrconn.Q("disease")|solrconn.Q("heart"))).highlight("content").highlight("title")
```

The above query is running accurately but i want to make this portion dynamic

```
solrconn.Q("disease")|solrconn.Q("heart")
```

For this i am doing

```
search_words=search_text.split(" ")
bitwiseQuery=""
count=0
for word in search_words:
    count=count+1
    if count<len(search_words):
        bitwiseQuery+='solrconn.Q("'+word+'")|'
    if count==len(search_words):
        bitwiseQuery+='solrconn.Q("'+word+'")'

search_record=(solrconn.query(bitwiseQuery)).highlight("content").highlight("title")
```

But it is not giving me any result , Any Idea how can I do this...

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is:

```
search_words = search_text.split(" ")

query = solrconn.query()

for word in search_words:
    query |= solrconn.Q(word)

search_record = query.highlight("content").highlight("title")
```

Your version above is trying to literally search for "solrconn.Q" in the search results.